# Is it possible to transfer to hardcore league from standard one?

Tags: path-of-exile

When you start a game you can choose do you want to play in standard or hardcore league. If you choose hardcore and die in there you get transfered to standrard league.

Now my question is, if you start in standard league is there any way to get to the hardcore league with that character, or of course if your character got transfered to standard league because you died with him/her in hardcore is there a way to get back. If you die in hardcore league and get transfered to standard, is your only way back to hardcore making a new character?

I've read on wiki that transfer to standard is permanent, but i just want to make sure that that means there is no way back to hardcore.

Comment: The entire idea of hardcore is your only get ONE chance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it wouldn't make any sense since the idea of the hardcore league is that you only have ONE chance/life.  Once you get killed, you fall back to "default"/"standard" league.

> Hardcore Typically, “hardcore mode” in action RPGs involves
>   permadeath. A character killed in this mode cannot be accessed any
>   more. In Path of Exile, slain hardcore characters revert to the parent
>   non-hardcore league. This system encourages non-hardcore players to
>   try the hardcore game mode, while still permanently removing hardcore
>   characters from the economy when they die.

Source: http://www.pathofexile.com/leagues

Answer (score 1):

"Hardcore" in any kind of roguelike traditionally means "one death". No, there's no way to enter "one death" league after you've been to "more than one death" league simply by their definitions.

Answer (score 0):

No and problably will never exist. The point of hardcore is that it is some sort of pemadeath. The entire server is a hardcore one.
The only way I see that work would be if they substituted it with a different leaguer.

Right now:
Default = Server where, you die and nothing happen, like in a usual mmorpg
Hardcore = Server where, you die your char and it goes to deafault

The new thing I talk about:
Default = Server where, you die and nothing happen, like in a usual mmorpg
Hardcore = Server where, you die your char goes to a alternate world that is like hardcore one but if you die, nothing will happen, like the usual mmorpg. This would be not a third server and if multiple hardcore servers exist, each one will have their own sub-world.

In this case guys that died on hardcore cant play with guys on default.
I could imagine in this case they allowing guys on default going to the "sub-world" of the hardcore league that work like default